# PHP | Include check.php to check if the user has a vpn

Tags: php, html, vpn

so i have a loading page for my website and i got a script somewhere that uses getipintel to see if a user is using a vpn. I was wondering how i would include that in my loading page so that when my loading page first loads it would run that php file and if the user has a vpn clear the page and display 403 Access Denied

Here is the check code http://pastebin.com/DXKmebvd

I've so far tried:
include 'check.php'
require 'check.php'
and all that and i can't seem to get it to work

```
<?php
function checkProxy($ip){
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        global $ip;
        $contactEmail="4horsemen@hitler.rocks"; //you must change this to your own email address
        $timeout=5; //by default, wait no longer than 5 secs for a response
        $banOnProability=0.99; //if getIPIntel returns a value higher than this, function returns true, set to 0.99 by default

        //init and set cURL options
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        //if you're using custom flags (like flags=m), change the URL below
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://check.getipintel.net/check.php?ip=$ip&contact=$contactEmail");
        $response=curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);


        if ($response > $banOnProability) {
                return true;
        } else {
            if ($response < 0 || strcmp($response, "") == 0 ) {
                //The server returned an error, you might want to do something
                //like write to a log file or email yourself
                //This could be true due to an invalid input or you've exceeded
                //the number of allowed queries. Figure out why this is happening
                //because you aren't protected by the system anymore
                //Leaving this section blank is dangerous because you assume
                //that you're still protected, which is incorrect
                //and you might think GetIPIntel isn't accurate anymore
                //which is also incorrect.
                //failure to implement error handling is bad for the both of us
            }
                return false;
        }
}
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (checkProxy($ip)) {
    /* A proxy has been detected based on your criteria
     * Do whatever you want to here
     */
    echo "[403 Forbidden Error] - Access Denied<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Paste your code here please.

Comment: You can never reliably detect a vpn. Why do you care?

Comment: Why would i make this post if i didn't care?

Comment: i didn't say you didn't, i asked **why**

Comment: see comments of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768400/detect-client-location-using-client-ip so there is a method to detect vpn , a tricky one

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect if a user uses a VPN service by a PHP code. You can only detect if the user uses a proxy server in web browser settings and even this can't be detected all the time. Also you can detect TOR Node IPs too, but **NOT** a VPN!